# Fragment shader played in reverse

Tags: time, three.js, glsl, shader

I have this fragment shader that I found on shadertoy.com, and now I'm going to implement it via three.js. My issue is that I would really want to be able to go control the "time" of the shader. So that I can let it "play" and then "reverse" the effect to get it back to the starting point. It will also be interactive so it's not a question of an animation.

What would be the best way to do this?

[Here's](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldcGDX) the shadertoy effect.

Comment: Please post some effort, whatever you have been able to do.

Comment: Well, I'm quite new when it comes to fragment shaders, but my initial ideas is to save the frame data in arrays and then use that for going back and forth. But it seems complex due to the interaction. There might be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a shader can be played in reverse by replacing the `time` variable with something like `1000.0 - time`, where 1000.0 is the time you want to play backwards from.

But, in your posted example, the shader actually overwrites the input image every frame, so that **you can not do that in reverse**. To do something in reverse, it must be a function of time that is not dependent on some other state.

Comment: Thank you for the response Holger! Yes, I believe I need to either store the data for every frame, but that complicates the interaction part a great deal. I would like to think though that there's people with the same idea out there that managed to sort it out in a more elegant way.